# Copy one Recordset to another

Tags: vb6

Since I received so nice and fast solution to my problem, I will try again to get some help from you:

I opened two Recordsets.

```
 Set cmd1.ActiveConnection = cn1
 cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mov Where [Date] >= #" & DateA & "#;"
 Set RSold = cmd1.Execute

 Set cmd2.ActiveConnection = cn2
 cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mov"
 Set RSnew = cmd2.Execute
```

(I want to save only selected records of a file.)

I know how to copy record by record, but is there a 'Short Cut' to do it faster ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [**Deep Copy or Clone an ADODB recordset in VBA**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553594/deep-copy-or-clone-an-adodb-recordset-in-vba)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Dim i As Long
Do While Not RSold.EOF
    ' You can place if condition here
    RSNew.AddNew
    For i = 0 To RSold.Fields.Count - 1
        RSNew.Fields(RSold.Fields(i).Name) = RSold.Fields(i).Value
    Next i
    RSNew.Update
    RSold.MoveNext
Loop
```

This will copy records from RSold to RSnew recordset

Comment: One note: You may have to special-case any autonumber fields that you have so that they are skipped. Inside the For loop, add code that does a check for the field name, and skips setting the field.

Comment: Thanks Hassan. I am trying to do the copy as quick as possible.

Comment: @hassan : Above copy process making my new recodset status to close.

Answer (score 2):

You Can use code :

### Set RSNew = RSOld.Clone

```
@user1838163 :Saving the second Recordset as a file

Dim RFileNm  As String 
Dim fs
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

RFileNm  = "c:\temp\" & Trim(RFileNm) & ".adt"
fs.DeleteFile (RFileNm)
RSNew .Save RFileNm, adPersistADTG
RSNew .Close
RSNew .Open RFileNm, , , , adCmdFile
```

Comment: Thanks Preeti. If I use the 'Clone', how do I save the second Recordset as a file ?

Comment: Thank you.  When I run the CLONE line, I get the following Error message:  "Current recordset does not support bookmarks. This may be a limitation of the provider or of the selected cursortype"  What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The recordset is probably a ForwardOnly, ReadOnly recordset. Make sure the table has a Primary Key.

Comment: Ok.Good. Got that. Now It is runing, but the File created can not be open in ACCESS. The Error message is "Not recognized file format".     Sorry... I appretiate your help.

Comment: create access file in place of ".adt" file

Comment: If I create the Access File, then the Error say that the File is already exist. If I use the extention as ".MDB", then I can not open the File using Access.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want by doing it all at once.

```
Dim objPB As New PropertyBag

objPB.WriteProperty "rs", RSOld
Set RSNew = objPB.ReadProperty("rs")

Set objPB = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you Joe. This is exactly what I am Looking for.  When I run the code, I am getting an Error "No such interface supported.       -2147467262.

Comment: Please assist. I am still stuck with this problem. Surched the net, can not find solution.

Comment: @Joe Majsterski : I want to update new recorset i.e RSNew.But above copy process not allowing me to update record set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CLONE is going to do what you want.  It just gives you another view of the same recordset you already have. This allows you to use multiple bookmarks and so forth, but the recordset is still attached to the same database the original was.  I also need a way to copy the recordset and save it to a new database in a new format.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  FYI, if you don't have the answer to the question, it's best to put your content in a comment rather than an answer.