# How to copy one record set to another in VB

Tags: vb.net, vb6, recordstore

I have a record set, I want to copy its data to another record set.

```
Dim rsAttributes,LoggedInUserId,rsAttributes1
Set rsAttributes = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set rsAttributes1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set rsAttributes = CALL DB TO GET DATA.
```

Now How can I copy rsAttributes  value/data to rsAttributes1 .
I tried with CLONE method, but did not work.

Comment: Is this *VBScript* + *Classic ASP*? - [Deep Copy or Clone an ADODB recordset in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553594/deep-copy-or-clone-an-adodb-recordset-in-vba) (Removing the `as <type>`)

Comment: Not working for me :(

Comment: "Not working for me" isn't very helpful when you want the advice