# clone a recordset which has some attachments

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, recordset, attachment-field

I wanted to copy a recordset to an another.

I found this code:

```
Do While Not rs(1).EOF
    ' You can place if condition here
    rs(2).AddNew
    For i = 0 To rs(1).Fields.Count - 1
        rs(2).Fields(rs(1).Fields(i).name) = rs(1).Fields(i).Value
    Next i
    rs(2).update
    rs(1).MoveNext
Loop
```

It works, but the problem is that I have some attachments fields in my recordsets and the loop block on them.  Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: have you seen [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25554406/2140173)? I am not quite sure it will work with the attachments but its worth testing yourself

Comment: Which line of code??  Gives what Error message?