# Check if ADODB Recordset contains value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, stream, adodb, recordset

I have a [Recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado) which has 1 column/field of data/records.

It has up to about hundreads or thousands of string values depending on the date range picked.

I then clone that data into a [Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/stream-object-ado) (as explained in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25554406) to another question) to keep it and reuse the Recordset. That Stream can be turned back into a new Recordset if needed or (probably) an array of some sort.

Later in the code I need to check if some values are in that Stream/Recordset/Array/etc.

Other than turning the Stream back into a Recordset and use a normal loop with [Recordset.Move methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-ado) ([example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-example-vb)) to check if each of those values are or not in the stored data, is there any other more efficient way to check it?

Comment: If you want to persist a recordset you can use a client-side cursor and disconnect it.  If you need to save it to a file you can use the `Save` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/persisting-data?view=sql-server-2017  If you need to check for specific values you can use the `Find` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/find-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The `Find` method is what I was looking for. Thanks @TimWilliams.

Answer (score 3):

From [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/bof-eof-properties-ado?view=sql-server-2017):

> Use the **BOF** and **EOF** properties to determine whether a **Recordset** object contains records or whether you have gone beyond the limits of a **Recordset** object when you move from record to record.
>
> The **BOF** property returns **True** (-1) if the current record position is before the first record and **False** (0) if the current record position is on or after the first record.
>
> The **EOF** property returns **True** if the current record position is after the last record and **False** if the current record position is on or before the last record.
>
> If either the **BOF** or **EOF** property is **True**, there is no current record.

---

So you could check to see if either of these properties are true, then you would know there is no current record.

Or you could do the opposite, and check to see if neither are true. Example:

```
If Not Rs.BOF And Not Rs.EOF Then
    ' Do something with your recordset
End If
```